# String Compression to Character ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a String that I am compressing to an array of characters with the count. I am not getting the last the count of characters in the string.

```
public class StringComp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String st = "aaabbccaaaaadddd";
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 1;
        char ct;

        for(int i = 0; i < st.length() - 1; i++) {
            if(st.charAt(i) == st.charAt(i+1)) {
                count++;
            }else {
                ct = Integer.toString(count).charAt(0);
                chars.add(ct);
                chars.add(st.charAt(i));
                count = 1;  
            }
        }
        System.out.println(chars.toString());

    }

}
```

My output:

```
[3, a, 2, b, 2, c, 5, a]
```

My output should be:

```
[3, a, 2, b, 2, c, 5, a, 4, d]
```

I can't seem to find the bug in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the final count after the loop:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < st.length() - 1; i++) {
    if(st.charAt(i) == st.charAt(i+1)) {
        count++;
    }else {
        ct = Integer.toString(count).charAt(0);
        chars.add(ct);
        chars.add(st.charAt(i));
        count = 1;  
    }
}
ct = Integer.toString(count).charAt(0);
chars.add(ct);
chars.add(st.charAt(st.length()-1));
```

Also note that it's a bad idea to store the count as a single `Character`. What if the count is larger than 9?

Comment: Eran yes you are right about that. Thanks for that!!